# Подскажите плагин для реализации слайдера?

Tags: javascript, slider, плагин

есть макет слайдера http://joxi.ru/L21aleyIgl65D2.
Подскажите плагин для реализации такого.

Answer (score 0):

Вот хороший слайдер с большим количеством настроек [swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/)

Так же вот примерный вариант, только нужно настроить верстку [codepen](https://codepen.io/marcomarasco/pen/XqdXyy)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Assign some jquery elements we'll need
  var $swiper = $(".swiper-container");
  var $bottomSlide = null; // Slide whose content gets 'extracted' and placed
  // into a fixed position for animation purposes
  var $bottomSlideContent = null; // Slide content that gets passed between the
  // panning slide stack and the position 'behind'
  // the stack, needed for correct animation style

  var mySwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true,
    roundLengths: true,
    loop: true,
    loopAdditionalSlides: 30,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
.swiper-container {
    position:relative;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 300px;
}
.swiper-container > .swiper-slide__content {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: 300px;
  display:flex;
  background: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  transition:all 200ms linear;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  
  &.swiper-slide-active{
    transform: scale(1);
    background: #fc0
  }
}
.swiper-slide__content {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.0/js/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5
        </div>
    </div>
      <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>
```